# Probabilities for each high card hands in draw poker

Tags: probability

What are the probabilities in draw poker of being dealt

- 3 cards to a flush, straight flush or royal flush
- 4 cards to a flush, straight flush or royal flush
- 3 cards to a straight
- 4 cards to a straight

I get probabilities and number of hands higher than the possible high card hands 1,302,540 these are part of?

Comment: Can you clarify your question? When calculating the odds of getting a flush draw, you don't count them for each suit.

Comment: The question doesn't need clarifying. But you can probably remove the information about how you got the wrong answer! That isn't helpful. :)